# convert list into string in python3

Tags: python

Right now I am having a list

```
>>> deints
[10, 10, 10, 50]
```

I want to print it as `10.10.10.50`. I made it as

## Method 1

```
>>> print(str(deints[0])+'.'+str(deints[1])+'.'+str(deints[2])+'.'+str(deints[3]))
10.10.10.50
```

Are there any other ways we can acheivie this ?

Thank you

Comment: `print('.'.join(map(str, deints)))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a list to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906092/converting-a-list-to-a-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
print('.'.join(str(x) for x in deints))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Even though it is for python 2 I understood what I need to add to make it run in python 3

Answer (score 5):

This is *very* simple. Take a look at [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
print '.'.join([str(a) for a in deints])
```

---

Citation from the docs:

> **str.join(iterable)**
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable *iterable*. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: @Raja, this just concatenates all the elements inserting a period as a separator. You also need to convert each number to a string first.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method on strings and have to convert the data in the list to strings first.

```
>>> '.'.join(map(str, deints))
'10.10.10.50'
```

`join` takes the string as a delimiter and concatenates the content of the list with this delimiter between each element.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but the problem here is that you need to `'.'.join`

Comment: Ah, right. But the abstraction should have been possible. It's funny, [first time I answered this kind of question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053236/python-equivalent-for-phps-implode/12053276#12053276) I got positive reputation ...

Comment: I need an integer not again in string. I have found what I need. Thank you

Comment: @Raja: The list is unaltered. `map` applies the call to `str` to the list and gives back the changed result (an _iterable_  with strings) which is then used by `join`.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `str.join()` is the shortest way

```
'.'.join(map(str, deints))
```

or if you dislike `map()` use a list comprehension

```
'.'.join([str(x) for x in deints])
```

you could also do it manually, using `*` to convert the `deints` list into a series of function arguments

```
'{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(*deints)
```

or use `functools.reduce` and a `lambda` function

```
reduce(lambda y, z: '{}.{}'.format(y, z), x)
```

All return

```
'10.10.10.50'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a non-`join` solution.

```
>>> print(*deints, sep='.')
10.10.10.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert them into strings, then join them. Try using:

```
".".join([str(x) for x in x])
```